# How much will it cost to read from an S3 bucket in the same region but on different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I read it doesn't cost anything to read data from an S3 bucket on the same region within the same account.

However, I'm interested how much will it cost to read a GB from a different account's bucket, on the same region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be **no Data Transfer** cost, since the Amazon EC2 instance and Amazon S3 bucket are in the same region.

The owner of the bucket will be charged for the **GET Request** (`$0.0004 per 1,000 requests`). Apart from that, the fact that the bucket belongs to a different AWS Account will not impact cost.

Comment: Thank you John. Is there any reference I can look into? BTW how will the request be calculated if FUSE is used?

Comment: FUSE makes calls to Amazon S3 just like any other program. It will result in charges for API calls (as above). It doesn't matter _what_ is making the call. It only matters _from where_ the request is being made when determining Data Transfer costs. All Amazon S3 pricing information is on: [Cloud Storage Pricing | Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)

Comment: Thanks you again.